# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT ao tentar simular aplicativo no XCODE

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, xcode

Estou tentando testar um aplicativo no xcode mas estou recebendo esse erro no main:

> ```
> int main(int argc, char* argv[])
> {
>     @autoreleasepool {
>         int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
>         return retVal;
>     }
> }
> ```

nessa variavel retVal mostra o erro:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

O completo log:

```
2019-03-26 16:23:00.486176-0300 JControle App[2350:144574] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
2019-03-26 16:23:00.803822-0300 JControle App[2350:144574] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///Users/jsoftwares4/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/32658139-1ADE-483D-90BE-5DCA0D6D2B1A/data/Containers/Data/Application/E3865663-F803-4A7F-975B-B94472E14FFA/Library/Cookies/japp.jcontrole.binarycookies
2019-03-26 16:23:04.825359-0300 JControle App[2350:144574] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7ff2d4c06460> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d30f1bb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010bc75735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d30ed29 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010b6a0de4 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000011a504573 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d2facfd -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    6   UIKitCore                           0x000000011a5012b9 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1814
    7   UIKitCore                           0x000000011a501d17 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 214
    8   UIKitCore                           0x000000011a893eee -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 77
    9   UIKitCore                           0x000000011a89450c -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 272
    10  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a892b25 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1357
    11  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0b14e9 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866
    12  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0ba29c +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    13  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0b1126 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 233
    14  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0b1ae0 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 1085
    15  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0afcb5 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 795
    16  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0af95f -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 435
    17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0b4a90 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 584
    18  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0b580e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    19  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0b47ef -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 221
    20  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a0b993a -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    21  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a89144e -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
    22  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a435d09 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 357
    23  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f50d2da -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 448
    24  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f518443 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 271
    25  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f517b3a __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 53
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eb96602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010eb99b78 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 301
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f54cba8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f54c860 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010f54ce40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d274721 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d273f93 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d26e63f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d26de11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001111f11dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    36  UIKitCore                           0x000000011a89481d UIApplicationMain + 140
    37  JControle App                       0x0000000109a3ddc1 main + 65
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ec0c575 start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei colocar o GoogleService-Info.plist na raiz e coloquei no config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
        <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>
```

mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1):

Eu removi a plataforma ios com o comando **ionic cordova platform rm ios** e adicionei novamente **ionic cordova platform add ios**, funcionou para mim.

Comment: pra mim, tive que atualizar a versão do plugin BackgroundMode